Asian film about an orphan, nomadic cab driver who helps a woman cover up a murder
I think the film was Korean, and it may have been made around or a little before 2010. But, I recall this much of the plot:
There was a cab driver who lived a nomadic lifestyle and had grown up as an orphan. He had a unique birthmark.
The film explores a little of his life as a cab driver before he winds up at an apartment complex where he develops a spotty friendship with a woman who has an abusive partner.
One night the woman kills her partner in self-defense, and she gets the driver to help her bury the body. The two then have what feels like a long, romantic relationship. The woman talks about a fire in the apartment complex that killed her parents, and the two seem to connect.
However, when the driver confesses he has fallen in love with her, she laughs at him. He hits her, and she only laughs more because she has taken harder punches. 
The cab driver eventually murders her and buries her body then leaves the complex one stormy night.
As he's leaving, he realizes that his "birthmark" was a scar from the same fire that killed the woman's parents and that the woman had been his sister.

Sounds like the fatalistic Korean horror film Sorum from 2001.

Yong-hyun moves into a creepy apartment which seems somehow familiar to him. His apartment was formerly occupied by a writer who burned to death in his room, but that doesn't seem to bother the detached young taxi driver. Across the hall from him is Jin-young who endures daily beatings from her husband. Her husband knows of a brutal murder that occurred about 30 years ago within the walls of this building and mysteriously touches on all their lives. 

The cab driver's body is scarred; he falls for his neighbor, her husband is killed, and he ends up killing her, only to discover that she was his sister. Here's the trailer:




YES!! Thank you so much; I've wanted to find this one for years!
